# Python, copying a rank 2 list structure with different values

Tags: python, list

Using python 3.6

Say I had this `dictionary` and `list` structure of `keys`:

```
dictionary = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5}

keys = [['a','b'], ['c','d','e']]
```

Whats the best way to get this?

```
values = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach with a `map`:

```
dictionary = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5}   
keys = [['a','b'], ['c','d','e']]

items = [list(map(dictionary.get, k)) for k in keys]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
```

One huge plus point is it's a lot more robust with handling non-existent keys (thanks, @Ev.Kounis!).

---

Alternative ft. Ev Kounis involving returning a default value on no-key:

```
items = [[dictionary.get(x, 0) for x in sub] for sub in keys]
```

Comment: Yeah that's awesome too! wish i could accept two answers. :)

Comment: @JamesSchinner The other answer is faster by 1 microsecond. But as far as succinctness goes, doesn't get much better than this. Cheers.

Comment: @JamesSchinner The advantage of this approach over the one by Ajax1234 is that it does not raise an error if you have an element in the list that does not appear as key in the dict. With some more coding you can supply a custom default value to cover that case.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Well I'll be. You're right, I didn't realise that. :)

Comment: That's a good point. having `.get` is pythonic in the sense it's explaining what its doing.

Comment: @JamesSchinner Don't forget what Ev Kounis said. If that influences your decision on whose answer to accept, so be it (;

Comment: Thanks for heads up! That would probably happen in my intended use case.

Comment: You can do something like: `items = [list(map(lambda x: dictionary.get(x, 0), k)) for k in keys]`. You can replace 0 with the default value you want to have.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Was trying to avoid lambdas since they tend to be clunky in maps, but if default value is needed, then that's the way to go.

Comment: Thanks all, always such succinct quick answers.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Unless you drop the `map` and do `[[dictionary.get(x, 0) for x in sub] for sub in keys]` or use `functools.partial`

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
dictionary = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5}

keys = [['a','b'], ['c','d','e']]

new = [[dictionary[b] for b in i] for i in keys]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: That's the best list comprehension, I've seen... so simple and elegant. Thanks mate! That's an answer and a half.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: I had to give the answer to Coldspeed. Just for the error handling. This has opened my eyes to nested comprehensions!

Comment: Ok no problem. Glad I could help you.